# How to add an automatically-updating hyperlink to a SharePoint folder in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, hyperlink, sharepoint

I have an Excel sheet that I want to add hyperlinks to. These hyperlinks should take the user to a browser site where an online SharePoint folder is located. This is easy enough, but the issue is that I want this hyperlink to update automatically if the folder is renamed, moved, etc.

So for example, if I have a SharePoint folder

```
Animals/Dogs/Labradors/Billy
```

I want to be able to grab its link, for example:

https://animalcompendium.sharepoint.com/Animals/Dogs/Labradors/Billy/

and link to it in the Excel file. However, if I move this folder to another location in SharePoint, such as:

```
Animals/Dogs/Bulldogs/Billy
```

I want the link to update in the Excel file as well, i.e.:

https://animalcompendium.sharepoint.com/Animals/Dogs/Bulldogs/Billy/

Is there any way to set this up?

Thanks.

Comment: That's quite a wish list. You are asking for Excel, a spreadsheet tool, to update links to a website? That's not possible and for good reason. It's a security issue. Excel is in no way designed for this.

Comment: Fair enough. I figured maybe there was some kind of integration between SharePoint and Excel which allows me to do this kind of thing. Looks like I'll have to break it to the person asking me to do this that they'll have to update the hyperlinks manually :p. Thanks for the reply.